# How can use a 3D map with 2D characters (Unity)?

Tags: unity, 2d, 3d, maps

I tried to search something about it but I can't find any complete or well-explained tutorials about how to use a 3D map with 2D characters and items, like Ragnarok or Final Fantasy Tactics.

If there is no tutorials about this topic, are there any recommendations for studying the subject? I've already developed some games using XNA, but only 2D games, I've never tried to use 3D models, nor have I used Unity to develop games.

Comment: For further inspiration, check out Tiny Wizard, a game developed in Unity https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17881592/zink/tinywizard/gcgp3.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from using 2D sprites in a 3D world.

Unity has support for 2D, 2.5D and 3D in all combinations of the set together.

*"I want 3D models in a 2D game."* - Fix the camera to a pan only system and use 3D models.

*"I want 2D models in a 3D game."* - Fix the camera to follow a 2D sprite but use the 3D character controller.

Try it. If it doesn't work or you have issues along the way, come back and we can help!